# Applycurrent values only shows the first value

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have the following code:

```
paciente.cantidad.ForEach(Sub(x)
                           crParameterDiscreteValueCantidad = New ParameterDiscreteValue
                           crParameterDiscreteValueCantidad.Value = x
 crParameterValuesCantidad.Add(crParameterDiscreteValueCantidad)
                                  End Sub)
crParameterFieldDefinitionCantidad.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValuesCantidad)
```

But in the crystal report, it only shows the first value of the array repeated.
If there are 5 items, it shows the first one 5 times.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `crParameterValuesCantidad` before calling `ApplyCurrentValues`?  Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it contains what is expected